# Python Pytorch and Pandas importing crashes the kernel macOS

Tags: python, pandas, macos, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
```

Works fine

But this makes kernel to restart:

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
```

[W 02:29:35.424 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info_reply: 4c1d9909-7259-438e-8511-dab91e7d774c
[I 02:29:35.923 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
kernel 5ba31d92-445a-42b5-8c03-76ea14c3db97 restarted
[I 02:29:38.006 NotebookApp] Kernel interrupted: 5ba31d92-445a-42b5-8c03-76ea14c3db97

macOS 12.5.1 M1 chip
pandas 2.0.0
pytorch 2.0.0

Tried to uninstall python, change environments, reinstall packages, nothing helps.